# Wordpress configuration via Raspberry

Tags: wordpress, webserver, raspberry-pi

I build a `LAMP`(Linux,Apache,MySQL,php) server with Wordpress using `raspberry pi 2`, following this tutorial: https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress/worksheet/
However, I'm stuck on step number 6 - I cannot configure `wordpress`. Normally, when I type in the IP address of the `Raspberry` in the browser I should see a wordpress error page. However, it is not the case and I have 404 error message:

```
404 Not Found
The requested URL /blog was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) Server at 192.168.0.100 Port 80
```

I did all of the previous steps and got the expected results. At the beginning I installed Apache and could see the test HTML web page. After that I installed `php`, `mysql` and `wordpress`. I created a database that will be used by  `wordpress`.

Can you give me an advice what to do to solve the problem? I know it is difficult to find the problem, but any idea about what to do would help me.
Thanks,
George

Comment: This is usually because you've installed WordPress in a different location. On your command line, go to `/var/www/` and run `ls -l` to see what files are there.

Comment: Initially I installed by mistake WordPress in two locations. However, after that I deleted one of the installations and right now WordPress is installed in '/var/www/'. When I run the 'ls -l' command, I see the correct contents. And yet, I still have the same problem.